# Cannot find function send in object (discord webhook url)

Tags: javascript, html, discord

I'm developing a website with a form...
I'm trying to get the data submitted from my form
and sent as a discord webhook.

here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
  function sendWebhook() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "webhook url");

    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

    var params = {
      username: "landon sucks",
      avatar_url: "",
      content: "msg"
    }

                    
    request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
  }
</script>
```

anyway, when sending a message, It returns error:

> {"result":"error","error":{"message":"Cannot find function send in object this is where the discord webhook url is","name":"TypeError","fileName":"script","lineNumber":86,"stack":"\tat script:86 (postMessageToDiscord)\n\tat script:66 (doPost)\n"}}

So what im getting is... my site is not able to get the send function of the webhook.

What is wrong here? how can I fix this?
someone help.

Ive done some research and found nothing

Comment: *"code above was weirdly formatted cause stack overflow is weird"* - yup, always put the blame on the tool...

Comment: @TJ LOL I mean yeah stack did format it weirdly